# How to position three divs horizontally

Tags: html, css

I want to get structure like this:

```
---------------------------------------------
| head                                      |
---------------------------------------------
|left-menu||---content-div-------------------
| fixed   ||                     |          |
|         ||    content-left     | con-right|
|         ||--------------------------------|
```

css file:

```
.left-menu {
    position:fixed; /* fix menu, no scroll  */
    left:0;
}
.content-div {
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    left:150px;
}
.content-right {
    width: 310px;
    float: right;
}
.content-left {
    float: left;
}
```

divs:

```
<div>
    <div class="left-menu" >    </div>

    <div class="content-div">
        <div class="content-left">  </div>
        <div class="content-right"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get `content-right` in the next line, not in the same line with `content-left`, like i have `content-left` `width=105%`, but i don't. I tried this and some other suggestion, but no luck. How can i fix this problem?

Comment: The weird thing is that I can not reproduce your issue. If you look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zxuoec0r/) you will see that your setting just works fine. I suspect that your problem lies within a higher wrapper div or something like that

Comment: Insert long text in content-left, content-right goes to next line

Comment: That is because you do not set the `width` property of the `content-left`. If you set the `width` of the `content-left` property it will work;) see [DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/zxuoec0r/2/)

Comment: It works with fixed width (px). I need flexible from left-menu to content-right. Like 'width: calc(100% - 310px);' but for all css.

Comment: than you need to set all the values of each div in percentage. You might want to change `310px` into something like `20%`

Comment: Thanks, but i solve it with `Flex`.

Comment: no problem! ;) flex is definitely a good solution. Just wanted you to inform that there are other methods! :) Your pick which to choose;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}
.left-menu {
  position: fixed;
  /* fix menu, no scroll  */
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}
.content-div {
  margin-left: 150px;
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
.content-right {
  flex: 0 0 310px;
}
.content-left {
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left-menu"></div>
  <div class="content-div">
    <div class="content-left"></div>
    <div class="content-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) looks awesome and easy-use with divs. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ronency/fxcmdaue/) for the demo

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="header">HEADER</div>
    <div class="left-menu" >LEFT MENU</div>

    <div class="content-div">
        <div class="content-left">CONTENT LEFT</div>
        <div class="content-right">CONTENT RIGHT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header { 
  height: 70px;
  background: blue;
}
.left-menu {
  width: 120px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 70px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.content-div {background: yellow;margin-left: 120px}
.content-div div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
}
.content-left {background: aqua;}
.content-right {background: green;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Position anything is a pain, I suggest using bootstrap for something like this.

(I just saw the comment above me about suggesting the same thing but I'll give you the code so you can implement it just incase)

Bootstrap supplies a nice CDN that you can throw in your html and have bootstrap wherever you go!

So put all of this in your html...

```
<html>
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

   </head>

 <body>

 <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
         <h1>Header</h1>
       </div> <!-- col-lg-12" -->
     </div> <!-- row -->


     <div class="row">

       <div class="col-lg-3" style="position: fixed;">
          <p>Left Menu Fixed</p>
       </div> <!-- col-lg-3 -->

       <div class="col-lg-6">
          <p>Content Left</p>
       </div> <!-- col-lg-6 -->

       <div class="col-lg-3">
          <p>Content Right</p>
       </div> <!-- col-lg-3 -->


      </div> <!-- row -->
 </div> <!-- container -->
 </body>
</html>
```

This will provide the layout you're suggesting.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for what you want

```
.left-menu {
position:fixed; /* fix menu, no scroll  */
left:0;
width: 150px;
height: 100%;
}
.content-div {
position:fixed;
left:150px;
right: 0px;
height: 100%;
}
.content-right {
float: right;
}
.content-left {
float: left;
}
```

Set a height and background-color on .content-left and .content-right if you want to see how they position themselves.

Comment: With long text in content-left, content-right goes to next line

Answer (score 0):

```
 .left-menu {
    position:fixed; /* fix menu, no scroll  */
    left:0;
    background: black;
    width:15%;
    height: 100%;
}
.content-div {
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    left:16%;
    background: red;
    width:84%;
    height: 100%;
}
.content-right {
    width: 310px;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    background: yellow;
}
.content-left {
    float: left;
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 310px);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, width: calc(100% - 310px); is working. So divs need width or what?

Comment: If you want to have a cross browser fix than you should not use calc() because this will only trigger modern browsers that supports CSS3 @JanOlMajti